# Unable to download images off Pixiv using pixivpy3

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm attempting to download images from Pixiv using the `pixivpy3` library. I'm able to authenticate and receive a list of images, but when using `requests` to download the image, I'm receiving a 403.

```
pic = random.choice(AllPics)
PicID = pic['id']
PicURL = f"https://www.pixiv.net/en/artworks/{PicID}"
SavedPicPath = f'imgTmp/{PicID}_p0.jpg'
response = requests.get(PicURL, 
                        headers={
                            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36', 
                            'referer' : PicURL,
                            'scheme' : 'https',
                            'accept' : 'image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8'
                            },
                        stream=True)
if os.path.exists(SavedPicPath):
    os.remove(SavedPicPath)
with open(SavedPicPath, 'wb') as Out_file:
    Out_file.write(response.raw)   
    DiscordFileObject = File(SavedPicPath)
```

The error I'm receiving is 
`TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'HTTPResponse'` and this is because `response` is a 403 error. I copied the headers directly from Chrome, so I'm not sure why I'm still getting this. I've also authenticated

Answer (score 0):

The issue is my URL was incorrect. The proper URL is `pic['image_urls']['large']`